# How do I save audio generated by a Processing sketch that uses ttslib?

Tags: processing, text-to-speech, audio-recording

I am working on a Processing sketch which is generating speech using the rita and ttslib libraries (rita is being used to generate Markov text chains, and ttslib is converting that text into speech).

What I can't seem to figure out how to do is save that speech as an audio file to my PC. Here is my current code:

```java
import ddf.minim.*;
import rita.*;
import guru.ttslib.*;

Minim minim;
AudioOutput out;
AudioRecorder recorder;

TTS voice1, voice2, voice3;
RiMarkov rm;
String[] sourceTextArray, script;
String title, sourceText;
int targetScriptLength;

void setup() {
  noLoop();
  minim = new Minim(this);
  out = minim.getLineOut();
  recorder = minim.createRecorder(out, "recording.wav");
    System.setProperty("mbrola.base","C:\\Users\\kandr\\Desktop\\Dropbox\\Coding & Web Design\\Processing 3\\libraries\\mbrola\\");
}

void draw() {
  generateScript("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random");
  prepareVoices();
  recorder.beginRecord();
  speakScript(script);
  recorder.endRecord();
  recorder.save();
}


void prepareVoices() {
  voice1 = new TTS("mbrola_us1");
  voice1.setPitch(180.0);
  voice1.setPitchRange(25.0);

  voice2 = new TTS("mbrola_us3");
  voice2.setPitch(120.0);
  voice2.setPitchRange(15.0);

  voice3 = new TTS("mbrola_us3");
  voice3.setPitch(0.0);
}


void generateScript(String sourceURL) {
  sourceTextArray = loadStrings(sourceURL);
  sourceText = join(sourceTextArray, " ");

  // find random article's title
  title = sourceText.substring(sourceText.indexOf("<h1 id=\"firstHeading\" class=\"firstHeading\" lang=\"en\">") + 53, sourceText.indexOf("</h1>"));
  title = title.replaceAll("<.*?>", "");

  // load the source text into our Markov generator
  rm = new RiMarkov(3);
  rm.loadText(sourceText);

  // set the target script size and instantiate an array to hold the lines
  targetScriptLength = 20;
  script = new String[targetScriptLength];

  // generate lines to populate the script 
  for (int l = 0; l < targetScriptLength; l++) {
    script[l] = rm.generateSentence();
  }
}


void speakScript(String[] scriptArr) {
  for (int s = 0; s < scriptArr.length; s+=2) {
    voice1.speak(scriptArr[s]);
    voice2.speak(scriptArr[s+1]);
  } 
}
```

As you can see, I have tried t use the Minim library's AudioRecorder class to record the audio that my sketch is outputting. However, no actual audio is being recorded - I just end up with an empty wav file. I also tried setting the AudioRecorder objects recordable source as an AudioInput, but that just recorded the sound from my laptop's mic.

I also looked at the Sound library that comes with Processing, but didn't see a suitable class for recording audio in there.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to figuring out how to get my sketch to record the audio that it is generating through ttslib?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for more specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. You need to break your problem down, and post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with just a few lines of runnable code. The question you are asking too broad. So try and edit the question in order to: ask what you want to do, show how you've previously tried to do it without success, and show the outcome of your failed attempts.

Comment: Okay, sorry. I have tried to add some more useful information above, including my current code.

Comment: Even if the code is still not runnable, I tried to reply below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, even though you edited the question, the code you posted still requires additional files and thus cannot be tested.

Anyway the problem seems to lie in Minim's API, so the audio routing needs to be done from outside the sketch. Because you are working on windows, it's as easy as changing the recording device to "Stereo Mix". This will reroute the audio output of the system into the input, thus being recordable by minim.

Here below is a small sketch I adapted using the [ttslib example](https://www.local-guru.net/blog/pages/ttslib) and the [minim recorder example](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/audiorecorder_class_audiorecorder.html), that records the speech produced by the ttslib library. If the audio is rerouted from the system settings.

```java
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;

import guru.ttslib.*;

Minim minim;

TTS tts;

AudioInput in;
AudioRecorder recorder;
boolean recorded;

AudioOutput out;
FilePlayer player;

void setup()
{
  size(512, 200, P3D);
  tts = new TTS();
  minim = new Minim(this);
  in = minim.getLineIn();
  recorder = minim.createRecorder(in, "test.wav", true);
  out = minim.getLineOut( Minim.STEREO );
  textFont(createFont("Arial", 12));
}

void draw()
{
  background(0); 
  stroke(255);
  for(int i = 0; i < in.left.size()-1; i++)
  {
    line(i, 50 + in.left.get(i)*50, i+1, 50 + in.left.get(i+1)*50);
    line(i, 150 + in.right.get(i)*50, i+1, 150 + in.right.get(i+1)*50);
  }

  if ( recorder.isRecording() )
  {
    text("Now recording, press the r key to stop recording.", 5, 15);
  }
  else if ( !recorded )
  {
    text("Press the r key to start recording.", 5, 15);
  }
  else
  {
    text("Press the s key to save the recording to disk and play it back in the sketch.", 5, 15);
  }
}

void keyReleased()
{
  if ( !recorded && key == 'r' ) 
  {
    if ( recorder.isRecording() ) 
    {
      recorder.endRecord();
      recorded = true;
    }
    else 
    {
      recorder.beginRecord();
    }
  }
  if ( recorded && key == 's' )
  {
    if ( player != null )
    {
        player.unpatch( out );
        player.close();
    }
    player = new FilePlayer( recorder.save() );
    player.patch( out );
    player.play();
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  tts.speak("Hi! This voice is being recorded");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I saved the above code as a new sketch. When I run it, it only records the sound from my mic, not the voice. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you change the system settings to use as recording device "Stereo Mix" instead of internal mic? For systems settings I mean the settings of your OS, not processing.

Comment: Ah, okay. Yes, that fixes the issue. Thanks!